# Multline equation along with aligned equations

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

How can I write the following? I have currently written it with an `align` environment and a `multline`, but I don't really know what is the correct approach to combine those (if that is the correct way at all).

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{aling*}
{
& R_{in}=R_{B}\parallel [r_{\pi}+(\beta+1)R_{E}]\\
& R_{out}=R_{C}\\
& A{u}=V_{out}/V_{in}\\
}
\end{align*}
%
\begin{multline*}
=[-g_{m}(R_{C}\parallel R_{L})]/[1\\
+(g_{m}+1/r_{\pi})R_{E}]
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `mathtools`, which upgrade `amsmath`define for such purposes math environment `multlined`. by it you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& R_{in}=R_{B}\parallel [r_{\pi}+(\beta+1)R_{E}]\\
& R_{out}=R_{C}\\
& A{u}=V_{out}/V_{in}\\
&\begin{multlined}[t]
=[-g_{m}(R_{C}\parallel R_{L})]/[1\\[1ex]
+(g_{m}+1/r_{\pi})R_{E}]
\end{multlined}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
R_{in}  & = R_{B}\parallel [r_{\pi}+(\beta+1)R_{E}]\\
R_{out} & = R_{C}\\
A{u}    & = V_{out}/V_{in}\\
        & = \begin{multlined}[t]
            [-g_{m}(R_{C}\parallel R_{L})]/[1\\[1ex]
            +(g_{m}+1/r_{\pi})R_{E}]
            \end{multlined}
\end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

The second equation shows usual expected to lookout.

**Edit:**

Slightly (for `\!`) better align of `multlined` with others equations is obtained if before it is placed `\!`:

```
   & = \!\begin{multlined}[t]
        [-g_{m}(R_{C}\parallel R_{L})]/[1\\[1ex]
        +(g_{m}+1/r_{\pi})R_{E}]
        \end{multlined}
```

Comment: You should include a `\!` before `\begin{multlined}` to get the spacing correct.

Comment: Mea maxima culpa ... I always forgot on this :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, with `align` and `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& R_\mathrm{in}=R_{B}\parallel [r_{\pi}+(\beta+1)R_{E}]\\
&R_\mathrm{out}=R_{C}\\
&A{u} \!\begin{aligned}[t] & =V_\mathrm{out}/V_\mathrm{in}\\
%
  & =[-g_{m}(R_{C}\parallel R_{L})]/[1+(g_{m}+1/r_{\pi})R_{E}]
\end{aligned}
 \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer although the second equation I like to be used in a multlined environment.